# Find the cell address when values are matched

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the cell address of the cell which is empty in column D when the jobid, dep, jobno are the conditions and store it in a variable for later use.

Example:

```
   A    B     C         D
1jobid  dep  job_no   Sequence   
2 aaa   FJ     1         1      
3 aaa   FJ     1         2
4 aaa   FJ     1         3
5 aaa   RJ     1         1
6 aaa   RJ     1         2
7 aaa   RJ     1         3
8 aaa   RJ     1          
9 aaa   FJ     1
```

for jobid=aaa and dep=rj and job_no=1
return D8

Comment: This is a rather simple task through Excel-formulas (`INDEX` + `MATCH`). If you want to go through VBA, you could do an iteration or use `.Evaluate`. Also, just to rule this out: Is it just a coïncidence, but in this case you are looking for the first empty cell. Is that always the case?

Comment: I tried it using an Excel-formula but since I'm fairly new to Excel and VBA I couldn't figure out how to check for multiple parameters using the index and match.
And regarding your question, yes always look for the first empty cell with the matched parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Code below

```vb
Function getAddress(colA As String, colB As String, colC As Double) As String
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = colA And .Cells(i, 2).Value = colB And .Cells(i, 3).Value = colC And .Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then
                getAddress = .Cells(i, 4).Address
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

Call the function like this:

`getAddress("aaa", "RJ", 1)`

**EDIT** As mentioned in the comments, added the conditions as parameters.

Comment: Better to pass these parameters as arguments to the function e.g. `Function getAddress(colA as string,colB as string, colC as string) As String` and then use it in code. No need to alter IF statement if you do it.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Thats a great Idea!

Comment: And I think you need to add an `Exit For` after finding match i.e. `getAddress = .Cells(i, 4).Address` statement.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a ton.

Comment: quick question let say I were to debug.print the get address it only prints one. suppose the empty string is updated then and there in that for loop how do i get it to check again until that condition fails?

Comment: @r00t How do you use the function? You could use an Loop over the empty cells and in each iteration call the function... Not quite sure I understand what you mean

Comment: @MG92   Alright let me clarify it a bit. So what I'm doing is after I get the required address when the conditions meet I get the max of the sequence and add one to the address. But I want to loop it such that It checks until there are no empty string for that condition.

Comment: I think I figured it out just removed the "Exit For". so basically it "end if" then "next i".

Comment: If you remove the `Exit For` the function will loop through all rows. If you replace the `Exit For` with `Debug.Print` it will print all the missing Adresses

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did. Thanks again for helping me understand.